# Excel - Find values in multiple tables

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

**Dear all,**

I have to make attendance report based on month & year (like mm/yyyy) and language level of few groups (A1 to C2).

I've got data in different tables (because people visit different level of language courses in different days), so currently I've made it into it like
[in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUeAz.png) (it was much worse before).

I wanted to get the attendance data (the 0, 1 etc...) from these tables (monday to friday) using the index match combo function (based on the dates) so I could count how many 1's and 0's every person will have for that month. 
The problem is I don't know how to use multiple arrays/tables in the index formula.

I've tried something like this to match the name and dates (don't laugh please):

```
=INDEX(OR(tbl_monday[#Data];tbl_tuesday[#Data];tbl_wednesday[#Data];tbl_thursday[#Data];tbl_friday[#Data]);MATCH([@Name];(tbl_monday[Name];tbl_tuesday[Name];tbl_wednesday[Name];tbl_friday[Name]);0);MATCH(1;(Table8[[#Headers];[11.9.2017]]=OR(tbl_monday[#Headers];tbl_tuesday[#Headers];tbl_wednesday[#Headers];tbl_thursday[#Headers];tbl_friday[#Headers]));0))
```

**TL;DR:**

I want to export the values in cells from the first picture (and other days aswell) mentioned here to [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVc76.png) and then to summarize it in [this overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxuH7.png). My boss will want to see the person with biggest absence/attendance so I need this final overview for sure.

Do you have ideas, how to do that more easily, than just copy it? There are a lot of persons and a lot of days to just copy/paste.
I hope I am clear with my problem.

**Thank you in advance!**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVc76.png)

Comment: Hi Marek ! Stop using excel and start using python + [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), you'll thank me somedays. Good luck

Comment: Hi Hugo, this is one-time task. I have to use excel because my whole company uses excel ( I cannot even use anything else that our IT doesn't approve), so I do not see point (yet) in using Python for my job. Thanks for the response tho

Answer (score 0):

Pěkný dotaz, pro ostatní tedy napíšu taky anglicky :-) I would probably try looking into PivotChart Wizard and Multiple consolidation of ranges. Tried to do it and here is something I came up with just playing around for couple of minutes. It would still create multiple columns because of differently named excuses, but the summary works and can be sorted to find the highest values. I could send you the file if you want...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was almost kinda what I needed, thank you, although I've found way around (a longer one tho). I will post it as an answer separately.